# format TAG release ref for Github Workflow Action

Tags: yaml, pipeline, release, continuous-deployment, github-actions

I would like to tag my release with v as prefix and product type as a suffix.
E.g. Initial release **v1.0.0-alpha01-internal** or **v1.0.0-alpha01-external**

Now I am running a GitHub action workflow to publish a release.

```
# The GITHUB_REF tag comes in the format 'refs/tags/xxx'.
    # So if we split on '/' and take the 3rd value, we can get the release name.
    run: |
      NEW_VERSION=$(echo "${GITHUB_REF}" | cut -d "/" -f3)
      echo "New version: ${NEW_VERSION}"
```

with the above code snippet, I get my new version **v1.0.0-alpha01-internal** or **v1.0.0-alpha01-external** now I don't want my version to be the same as TAG so I would like to cut v from start and -internal or -external from the end of the release TAG.

The expectation of a new version would be **1.0.0-alpha01**

Answer (score 0):

`NEW_VERSION=$(echo "${GITHUB_REF}" | cut -d "/" -f3) | cut -c 2- | cut -c 1-13` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

at this point your issue is just with string manipulation in Bash and has nothing to do with GH or GH Actions.

So you can just find what is the best way to modify a string in Bash. I recommend you start here:

https://www.baeldung.com/linux/bash-string-manipulation

```
TAG_VERSION=v1.0.0-alpha01-internal
TAG_VERSION=$(echo ${TAG_VERSION//v/})
TAG_VERSION=$(echo ${TAG_VERSION//-internal/})
TAG_VERSION=$(echo ${TAG_VERSION//-external/})
```

Or using [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html)

There is probably a better regex to use here but you can decide based on all the use cases

```
echo $TAG_VERSION | sed 's/-internal//g' | sed 's/-external//g' | sed 's/v//g'
```